# Angular 15 testing component using the inject() DI method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

I am refactoring one component to use the new `inject()` dependency injection and I can't find a way of testing it. The component works fine but all my tests are broken. I have seen many explanations in the web on how to use this (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75770010/how-to-unit-test-a-function-that-uses-the-new-angular-14s-inject-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76823924/angular-14-inject-in-unit-test-without-testbed))  with functions and services but they seem not to work with components. I tried them all but I am probably missing something. The suite always fail with the following error:

```
NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
```

but I can't make much sense out of it :(

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the component:

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppDomains } from '../models/kyc-enums.model';

@Component({ template: '' })
export abstract class KycBasePageComponent implements OnDestroy {
    // properties…

    constructor() {
        const route = inject(ActivatedRoute);
        this.appDomain = route.snapshot.data.appDomain;
    }

    // methods…
}
```

And this is my test file:

```js
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppDomains } from '../models/kyc-enums.model';
import { KycSteps } from '../models/kyc-steps';
import { KycBasePageComponent } from './base-page.component';
import { IBasePage } from './base-page.interface';

class ConcretePage extends KycBasePageComponent implements IBasePage {}

fdescribe('KycBasePageComponent', () => {
    let component: ConcretePage;
    let activatedRouteMock: ActivatedRoute = {
        snapshot: {
            params: { flowId: '111' },
            data: { appDomain: AppDomains.Onboarding },
        },
    } as unknown as ActivatedRoute;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ConcretePage, KycBasePageComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock }],
        });
    });

    it('should extend KycBasePageComponent', inject([ActivatedRoute], () => {
        component = new ConcretePage();
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
        expect(component.appDomain).toEqual('onboarding');
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you modify the below code like so? We need `super` on the constructor to call the abstract class constructor!

```
class ConcretePage extends KycBasePageComponent implements IBasePage {
    constructor() {super();}
}
...

...
it('should extend KycBasePageComponent', inject([ActivatedRoute], () => {
    component = new ConcretePage();
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.appDomain).toEqual('onboarding');
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Naren but calling super in the ConcretePage constructor didn't change the error.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I found out how to solve my problem. The component with the injected services must be instantiated inside an injection context. So, using my example it would look like (attention to the `create` method):

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppDomains } from '../models/kyc-enums.model';
import { KycSteps } from '../models/kyc-steps';
import { KycBasePageComponent } from './base-page.component';
import { IBasePage } from './base-page.interface';

class ConcretePage extends KycBasePageComponent implements IBasePage {}

fdescribe('KycBasePageComponent', () => {
    let component: ConcretePage;
    let activatedRouteMock: ActivatedRoute = {
        snapshot: {
            params: { flowId: '111' },
            data: { appDomain: AppDomains.Onboarding },
        },
    } as unknown as ActivatedRoute;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ConcretePage, KycBasePageComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock }],
        });
    });

    function create() {
        // This is where the magic happens!
        TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => {
            component = new ConcretePage();
        });
    }

    it('should extend KycBasePageComponent', () => {
        create();
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
        expect(component.appDomain).toEqual('onboarding');
    });
});
```